# How to override plugin Config in Grails?

Tags: grails, plugins, configuration

I'm using the excellent class-diagram plugin https://github.com/trygvea/grails-class-diagram, and would like to override the config value classSelection as set here: https://github.com/trygvea/grails-class-diagram/blob/master/grails-app/conf/ClassDiagramConfig.groovy in my apps Config.groovy file.

None of the following seem to work:

```
grails.plugins.class-diagram.classDiagram.config.defaults.classSelection = "com.mypackage.*"
grails.plugins.class-diagram.config.preferences.defaults.classSelection = "com.mypackage.*"
grails.plugins.class-diagram.classDiagram.config.preferences.defaults.classSelection = "com.mypackage.*"
```

how do i access the correct namespace in order to override the value?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The names of Config properties are arbitrary, they don't necessarily have to follow any specific pattern or convention like package name.

If you have only a single property to override you can use the "flattened" syntax:

```
classDiagram.preferences.defaults.classSelection = 'com.mypackage.*'
```

You can also declare Config properties using closure syntax (as in the example Config file) if you want to group several properties together:

```
classDiagram {
    preferences {
        defaults {
            classSelection = "com.mypackage.*"
            showAssociationNames = false
            showMethodReturnType = true
            showMethodSignature = false            
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the Grails plugin system doesn't automatically load `*Config.groovy` files from a plugin into an application's Config. A plugin developer can set up a plugin to merge a default `*Config.groovy` file into the application's Config, in which case usually the properties in an application's `Config.groovy` will override the Config properties supplied by a plugin.

Comment: I updated this answer to clarify some facts about how the Grails plugin system loads Config.groovy files from plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Properties set in your `Config.groovy` will override a plugin's Config.groovy properties if they have the same name. You're adding a package for the properties, but that's not necessary. Use

```
classDiagram.preferences.defaults.classSelection = "com.mypackage.*"
```